# How to specify rules to allow anyone to read a certain key/value pair

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to let any user see only the `name` and `email` parameter.

```
    "users": {
        "kanyesUID": {
            "name": "Kanye West",
            "email": "kwest@gmail.com",
            "sensitive_info": "a"
        },
        "taylorsUID": {
            "name": "Taylor Swift",
            "email": "tswift@gmail.com",
            "sensitive_info": "a"
        },
        "seacrestsUID": {
            "name": "Ryan Seacrest",
            "email": "rseacrest@gmail.com",
            "isAdmin": true
        }
     }
```

For the following code, I should get this output:

```
        "kanyesUID": {
            "name": "Kanye West",
            "email": "kwest@gmail.com"
        },
        "taylorsUID": {
            "name": "Taylor Swift",
            "email": "tswift@gmail.com"
        },
        "seacrestsUID": {
            "name": "Ryan Seacrest",
            "email": "rseacrest@gmail.com"
        }
```

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    print_snapshot_json(snapshot);
});
```

What would the rules need to be to allow this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with security rules.  You're attempting to use security rules as a filter to determine which fields will appear in search results, but that's not supported.  A query must be able to read **all** the data that would be returned by the query.  What you can do instead is split the public and private fields of each user into separate top-level nodes, so they can be queried for and protected separately.

For more details, please read the documentation, specifically the section titled "[rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters)".